# How to make checkmark stick to start of text? Tailwind

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a some paragraphs and I want to stick a checkmark in front of it using a React Icon component:

```
function HeadingBulletPoint(props) {
  return (
    <div className="mb-2 text-gray-500 font-medium flex">
      <GoCheck className="text-2xl mr-1"/><p className="">{props.children}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

where {props.children} is "blah blah blah" in this example.

The result is like this: [image: checkmarks are staying on the left]

But I don't want the checkmarks to stick to the left side, I want them to stick to the text, like this: [image: checkmarks are sticking to text]

How can I do that? I've been playing with all kinds of flex properties, but I can't seem to make it work...

Edit: [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/m4f21bNbi3) is an interactive example on Tailwind Playground. Again, I want to have the checkmark (the red "v" in this example) just next to the text like the dark picture above shows. The gray border is just for clarity.

Comment: Can you provide a complete reproducible example?

Comment: @tromgy Updated the post now with interactive example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the checkmark and the text are two block-level elements, and no amount of "flexing" can make them move next to each other for a case like this:

[image: checkmark can't flow into the next element]

What you can do though, is to make the checkmark an inline-level element by using `<span>` for instance. Here's an [example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/yYchgnqfam).

And in the context of your React app you can do something like:

```
export default function GoCheck() {
  return <span>✔️</span>;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
import GoCheck from './GoCheck';

export default function HeadingBulletPoint(props) {
  return (
    <div className="mb-2 text-gray-500 font-medium flex">
      <p className="text-center">
        <GoCheck/>
        {props.children}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then if the enclosing element is (copying styles from your Tailwind playground):

```
      <div className="mt-8 flex flex-col justify-center items-center max-w-xs">
        <HeadingBulletPoint>blah blah blah</HeadingBulletPoint>
        <HeadingBulletPoint>blah blah blah blah blah</HeadingBulletPoint>
        <HeadingBulletPoint>blah blah blah</HeadingBulletPoint>
        <HeadingBulletPoint>blah blah blah blah blah</HeadingBulletPoint>
        <HeadingBulletPoint>blah blah</HeadingBulletPoint>
        <HeadingBulletPoint>blah blah blah</HeadingBulletPoint>
        <HeadingBulletPoint>blah</HeadingBulletPoint>
        <HeadingBulletPoint>blah blah blah blah blah blah</HeadingBulletPoint>
      </div>
```

it should render like this:

[image: React render result]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by moving the checkmark element inside the paragraph and setting it to inline-block:

```
function HeadingBulletPoint(props) {
  return (
    <div className="mb-2 text-gray-500 font-medium flex text-center ">
      <p className=""><GoCheck className="text-2xl inline-block mr-2"/>{props.children}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you figured it out 

Answer (score 0):

on the GoCheck componenet you can use `style={{position: 'absolute'}}` it will take it out of the relative positioning.

Comment: Thanks, but now the checkmark is inside the other text. Putting a margin left on the content text makes it act very similar to before.

Comment: Can you share your code? You have to render every checkmark in the same separate line as the blahblah. BTW it is style={{position: 'absolute'}} sorry

Comment: Take a look at the interactive example linked from the main post.

Comment: I just figured it out, but thanks for the help anyways! I just posted the answer if you want to see how I solved it